# How to get the value of variables individually from property in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

It is difficult for me to formulate this question, so i'll try to show what i mean.

I have a property

```
def count_tax_rate(self):
    if self.deposit_value > 100:
        Deposits.objects.update(tax_rate=self.tax_rate+10)
        return self.tax_rate + 10
count_tax_rate.short_description = "Tax rate"
tax_rate_property = property(count_tax_rate)
```

Then i connect this property to my admin.ModelAdmin form.

```
class DepositAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('temporary_deposit_income', 'temporary_total_income', 'tax_rate_property',
                       'deposit_creating_date', 'deposit_end_date')
    form = DepositForm
```

And in my admin panel this gives me

```
Tax rate = 10
```

But i need to calculate and show more than one variable in my admin panel.

I tried to rewrite my property function

```
def count_tax_rate(self):
    if self.deposit_value > 100:
        Deposits.objects.update(tax_rate=self.tax_rate+10, total_income=self.deposit_value+100)
        return self.tax_rate + 10, self.deposit_value + 100
count_tax_rate.short_description = "Tax rate"
tax_rate_property = property(count_tax_rate)
```

But it gives me this

`Tax rate = (Decimal('10.00'), 200)`

I understand that this is the way property works.

**Is there any way to get multiple values from one property function or am i have to look for a completely different solution?**

PS. I need this values separately, so i can use them as different fields in readonly_fields.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def count_tax_rate(self):
    if self.deposit_value > 100:
        Deposits.objects.update(tax_rate=self.tax_rate+10, total_income=self.deposit_value+100)
        return f"Tax rate: {self.tax_rate + 10}, Deposit value: {self.deposit_value + 100}"
```

If I understood your question, you want multiple values in a single column. I don't know why you want to do this, I suggest you to use two properties and link them to two columns, but if you want to proceed this way, then you can just return a string with both the values.

I'm using an f-string here, but you can build the string as you prefer.

Comment: that's not exactly what I meant. i am trying to get the return values individually, so i can connect this values to a different readonly_fields, but right now they show in the same readonly_field.

Comment: Ok then no, I don't think you can. Just declare two properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should implement relationships between two models. For example you can have a parent table and a child table, which is going to be the `Deposit` table and connect the parent table with `Foreign Key` to the the `Deposit` one. So now you can have many deposits assigned **individually** to one parent.

I hope that helps. Please let me know if I got that right.